# Multi-part identifier error when adding a function to table- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have the following function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CurrentEmpCount()
RETURNS DECIMAL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetCount DECIMAL, @Return DECIMAL;

    SELECT @RetCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY DepartmentID

    SET @Return = @RetCount

    RETURN  @Return
END
```

When I try to add it to the department table with alter, I get an error:

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.CurrentEmpCount" could not be bound.

```
ALTER TABLE Department
    ADD WorkStations AS dbo.CurrentEmpCount
GO
```

Could anyone suggest anything to try out? In examples I've seen, they were doing it similarly.

Comment: I dont think you can add a function to a table Patrick. For what purpose?

Comment: (1) Your code doesn't make sense.  You have a `GROUP BY` that returns multiple  rows, but just has one return value.  (2) What does adding a function to a table mean?

Answer (score 4):

Your function should have an input for the `DepartmentID`. And you count number of employee for that `DepartmentID`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CurrentEmpCount
(
    @DepartmentID  INT        -- assuming that ID is INT
)
RETURNS INT                   -- count() returns an INTEGER not DECIMAL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetCount INT

    SELECT  @RetCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Employee
    WHERE   DepartmentID = @DepartmentID

    RETURN  @RetCount 
END
```

Then your Department table should be as follow

```
ALTER TABLE Department
    ADD WorkStations AS dbo.CurrentEmpCount(DepartmentID)
```

You need to pass in the `DepartmentID` of table `Department`

Alternatively you can just create a `VIEW` for the `Department` table

Note : use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` if you are storing numbers with decimal places. From [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `Numeric data types that have fixed precision and scale`

Comment: Are you doing this only for one department? I need it for all departments

Answer (score 1):

you cannot directly add function value as a column in a table.

What's your actual requirement

If you want department wise an employee count in the department table. 
 then you have to calculate  using below query

UPDATE  B
SET     B.dept_no_employee = A.no_count
FROM    Department B
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  COUNT(A.id) AS no_count
    FROM    Employee A
    WHERE A.dept_id = B.dept_id
)A

[image]
Else ignore the answer.

Comment: That's good, I want this result whenever my department table is queried with a select statement. Which approach should I use?

Comment: Yes if you want only count then you can use  select count(1),b.dept_name from employee a inner join department b on a.dept = b.dept_id group by dept_name